# Updating table error? (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently getting this error

```
[31-Aug-2018 15:50:46 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught 

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' 
in /home/crysuicn/public_html/products.php:22
Stack trace:
#0 /home/crysuicn/public_html/products.php(22): PDOStatement->fetch(2)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/crysuicn/public_html/products.php on line 22
```

Line 22 is:

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Therefore the error would be somewhere in here, but I do not see what the error could be.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["discount"])){
        if($_SESSION["discount"] != "na"){
            $sql = "SELECT users FROM discounts WHERE name=:promo";
            $query = $st->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array(
                'promo' => $name
            ));
            if($query->rowCount()>0){
                while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    if(!empty($row["users"])){
                        $usedips = $row["users"];
                        $usedips = $usedips.", ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                    }else{
                        $usedips = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                    }
                    $sql = "UPDATE discounts SET users=:updatedips WHERE name=:name";
                    $query = $st->prepare($sql);
                    $query->execute(array(
                        'updatedips' => $usedips,
                        'name' => $name
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $_SESSION["discount"] = "na";
```

Any help is much appreciated. I haven't had this error before so I am not sure where to go from here.
It does go through and updates the table

Comment: You can't use fetch with updates mate.

Comment: That is something I never knew, I appreciate that.

Comment: Also your while loop is processing `$query->` but inside your while loop you reuse `$query->` in the UPDATE query thus destroying your while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying your `$query` handle by reusing it on the UPDATE query thus the while loop gets broken.

So use another variable for the statement handle used in the UPDATE.

Its also better to prepare a query once and reuse it many times, just replacing the variables. This allows the database to compile and optimise the query only once, but run it many times. It's quicker for your script and places less unnecessary load on the database.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["discount"])){
    if($_SESSION["discount"] != "na"){
        $sql = "SELECT users FROM discounts WHERE name=:promo";
        $query = $st->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array('promo' => $name));

        if($query->rowCount()>0){

            // prepare once use many times
            $sql = "UPDATE discounts 
                    SET users=:updatedips WHERE name=:name";   
            $stmt= $st->prepare($sql);

            while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                if(!empty($row["users"])){
                    $usedips = $row["users"];
                    $usedips = $usedips.", ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                }else{
                    $usedips = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                }

                $stmt->execute(array('updatedips' => $usedips,'name' => $name));
            }
        }
    }
}
$_SESSION["discount"] = "na";
```

Comment: I appreciate that, That's something that I had just missed.

Answer (score 1):

You're recycling variable names and sabotaging your loop. Rename the inner "query", or while you're at it, structure it differently:

```
        $select = $st->prepare("SELECT users FROM discounts WHERE name=:promo");
        $select->execute(array(
            'promo' => $name
        ));

        $update = $st->prepare("UPDATE discounts SET users=:updatedips WHERE name=:name");

        if ($select->rowCount() > 0) {
            while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                if(!empty($row["users"])){
                  $usedips = $row["users"];
                  $usedips = $usedips.", ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                } else {
                  $usedips = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                }

                $update->execute(array(
                  'updatedips' => $usedips,
                  'name' => $name
                ));
            }
        }
```

Whenever possible give your variables meaningful, contextual names. `$query` is often too vague.

Plus use prepared statements effectively: Prepare once and execute many times if necessary.

It also looks like you're assembling a comma-separated value in a column which is a big problem for relational databases. Instead create a proper one-to-many relationship here. Try to avoid violating the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) by understanding the idea behind proper
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).